# Randomly changing numbers

Tags: python, random

Using Python, I wish to alter numbers from a list by adding a +1 or -1 to that number for a few (lets say 500) randomly selected numbers out of thousands of numbers.

I am familiar with the random number generator, however unsure what my next step to alter current numbers would be.

For example, these are a few of the numbers I wish to edit:

```
array([-0.5887, -0.3948,  2.7303, -0.4915, -0.2842,  2.7168, -0.6298,
       -0.2313,  2.5747, -0.5887, -0.3948,  2.7303, -0.6298, -0.2313,
        2.5747, -0.7114, -0.4042,  2.6477, -0.4915, -0.2842,  2.7168,
       -0.3596, -0.1205,  2.6922, -0.5133, -0.04  ,  2.5177, -0.4915,
       -0.2842,  2.7168, -0.5133, -0.04  ,  2.5177, -0.6298, -0.2313,
        2.5747, -0.3596, -0.1205,  2.6922, -0.2133,  0.0692,  2.6638,
       -0.3754,  0.1682,  2.469 , -0.3596, -0.1205,  2.6922, -0.3754,
        0.1682,  2.469 , -0.5133, -0.04  ,  2.5177, -0.2133,  0.0692,
        2.6638, -0.0574,  0.2702,  2.6393, -0.219 ,  0.3798,  2.4369,
       -0.2133,  0.0692,  2.6638, -0.219 ,  0.3798,  2.4369, -0.3754,
        0.1682,  2.469 ])
```

Comment: What did you try? What programming-language are you using? It sounds like you want a random-selection (without replacement) ```k < n``` to select the numbers to alter. Then iterate over the subset and throw a coin (uniform-number >= 0.5?) to add 1 or -1.

Comment: This question is too vague to answer. The answer depends heavily on the programming language, which you didn't specify. In many languages, this can be done trivially (1 or 2 lines of code in either R or Python) whereas in others it would take a bit more. If you are interested in combining arts and programming, you might enjoy the book [Data-driven Graphic Design](http://a.co/fxXni9z) by Andrew Richardson. It is one of the most visually beautiful programming books that I have ever seen.

Comment: I do apologise and thank you for your comments and suggestions, that seems like a very interesting book John. I am using python. 
I am a beginner when it comes to programming so mainly I follow tutorials, however I was not able to find something similar to what I want. I have around 300,000 numbers and I want to randomly change around 500 numbers at a time, either adding a +1 or -1 to that number without changing the structure of the numbers.

Comment: `Processing` (used in that book) has an active artist community associated with it. Here is a [somewhat typical example](http://reinoudvanlaar.nl/project/leavespattern/) of art that used Processing. Processing has a Python mode which seems to be becoming more popular.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one straightforward way via `numpy` library. This assumes your list of numbers is stored in a variable `lst`. I suggest you go through each line to ensure you understand what is happening.

There are plenty of resources on SO and elsewhere to help you on your journey.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import random

# convert data to numpy array
arr = np.array(lst)

# copy to test you are successful in final step
arr2 = arr.copy()

# get 20 random indices
to_change = random.sample(range(len(arr)), 20)

# increment those indices
arr[to_change] += 1

# check success
(arr != arr2).sum()  # 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you could do something like this:

```
import random

x = list(range(1,101))
indices = list(range(len(x)))
change = set(random.sample(indices, 10)) #randomly select 10 indices to change
x = [j+random.choice([-1,1]) if i in change else j for i,j in enumerate(x)]
```

The code works quickly even if `x` has 300,000 entries and you are changing 5000 of them. Using `set()` is key to getting decent performance since that that makes using `in` very rapid.